# What desktop chipsets support AMD's Rapid Virtualization Indexing?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, xen, amd-phenom

Rapid Virtualization Indexing (RVI) is a hardware virtualization feature that can potentially give significant performance improvement.  Intel's equivalent is Extended Page Tables. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_Virtualization_Indexing for more details.

My question is: **Does RVI require motherboard or chipset support? If yes, what desktop chipsets support it?** I've ordered a Phenom II CPU (which supports RVI) but I haven't bought the motherboard. I'll install XenServer or VMware ESXi (which both support RVI) on the new computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the MMU is included on the CPU die, I guess that MoBos / chipsets don't even need to know about nested page tables.

Comment: +1, correct. RVI and other NPT schemes only require CPU, Northbridge (integrated to CPU for AMD procs), and OS (hypervisor) support.

Comment: @Chris: From what you've said, I guess Intel's EPT would require the northbridge chipset to cooperate, right?

Comment: The MB must be Intel VT-d compatible (VT 2nd Gen); I'm not sure what the difference is from VT-x (VT 1st Gen). Some boards might be compatible via updates; check with your MB manufacturer.